# Typing in windows phone 7 simulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am a newbie in windows phone 7 development. In my project, I add a textbox control to the main form. When I run it, I want to type some text to this textbox by my keyboard (PC keyboard) but I can't. I just touch to the soft-keyboard (by mouse) only - too slow, so uncomfortable!
Could you tell me a way to solving this problem please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use the page up key board which will help to type in the emulatoor with ur keyboard than SIP .

There are also quite a few other shortcut keys available ..

You can find them on [Shortcuts keys for Developing on Windows Phone 7 Emulator](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/01/shortcuts-keys-for-developing-on-windows-phone-7-emulator/)

Comment: I prefer to give the exact answer here than giving the URL, Becoz nobody knows how long the site exists :)

Answer (score 5):

Push PgUp key on real keyboard and it allows you to type in the emulator.

Answer (score 3):

You can toggle hardware keyboard emulation while a textbox has focus using PAUSE or PGUP/PGDN.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog on switching to the keyboard in the WP7 emulator

http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2010/11/02/Invoking-the-Keyboard-in-the-Windows-Phone-7-Emulator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For entering in WP7 emulator.. use Pause/Break key on real key board.. After that you can enter in emulator using real keyboard.